# A surjective mapping that preserves the scalar product is a unitary operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ --- a surjective mapping preserving the scalar product, i.e. $\langle Tx, Ty \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle  $ . Prove that $T$ is a linear unitary operator.

So I can prove that $T$ is linear, because
$$\langle T(x+y), T z \rangle = \langle x+y, z \rangle = \langle x, z \rangle + \langle y, z \rangle = \langle Tx, T z \rangle  + \langle Ty, T z \rangle \Rightarrow T(x+y) = Tx + Ty,$$
and that $T$ is unitarian:
$$\langle Tx, Ty \rangle = \langle T^* T x, y \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle  \Rightarrow T^* T = I$$

My question is where the surjectivity of the operator $T$ is used here

Comment: Surjectivity is used to prove the linearity. You need $\{ Tz|z \in H \}$ to be dense in $H$ to conclude that $\langle T(x+y), Tz \rangle = \langle Tx + Ty, Tz \rangle \implies T(x+y) = Tx + Ty$. You can only talk about the adjoint operator after this.

Comment: You should also use surjectivity in the proof of $TT^{*}=I$ (or equivalently $T$ is invertible in this case). $T^{*}T=I$ only is not enough to ensure $T$ is unitary.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail why $\{Tz \mid z \in \mathcal{H}\}$ should be dense in $\mathcal{H}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You proved that $$\langle T(x+y),Tz\rangle=\langle Tx+Tx,Tz\rangle.$$
Why would that imply that $T(x+y)=Tx+Tz$? The reason is that $T$ is surjective, which allows you to replace $Tz$ by an arbitrary $w$; so you have
$$
\langle T(x+y)-Tx-Ty,w\rangle=0
$$
for all $w$. If in particular you take $w=T(x+y)-Tx-Ty$ you get that $\|T(x+y)-Tx-Ty\|=0$, which then implies $T(x+y)-Tx-Ty=0$. As mentioned in the comments, it is enough to have that $\{Tz:\ z\}$ is dense, because you can still get arbitrary $w$ by taking limits.

The second point is that it is not enough to have $T^*T=I$ to conclude that $T$ is a unitary. On a infinite-dimensional Hilbert space there exist non-surjective isometries, that is operators $S$ that satisfy $S^*S=I$ but do **not** satisfy $SS^*=I$. What happens is that, since $T$ is surjective, given an arbitrary $x$ you can write $x=Ty$ for some $y$, and then
$$
TT^*x=TT^*Ty=Ty=x.
$$
So $TT^*=I$.